# stuck with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is a basic explain of what's my problem:
I need to rewrite from `http://domain.com/file.php?name=xxxx`
to `http://domain.com/xxxx`

So, the problem is: I have some directories like images, css, include, etc., where files are stored, and instead of rewrite to `http://domain.com/xxxx` is going to directory itself.
here is my scrappy `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^index.html$         index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^help.html$          help.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.xml$       info.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$              file.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas how to fixit, and allow my stored files in that directories keep working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite rule that will redirect all requests to a page handler if the file doesn't actually exist at that location:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ path/to/pagehandler.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: still not rewrite, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set  tag in your files and then it will know where to go relatively or you can use full paths.